# NSUInteger casting

Tags: objective-c

I have the following statement:

```
NSLog(@"The count of the book is now: %i", [book.book count]);
```

This gives me a caution that I'm using the wrong format argument.

- 1) Why can't I print the count as an integer? (Wouldn't this make the most sense?)
- 2) What would be the correct way to write the above statement?

Comment: I don't have a compiler at hand at the moment, but NSUInteger is unsigned, so `%u` would be the correct format specifier. Another thing to consider is the bitwidth of `NSUInteger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but probably shouldn't print it as a signed integer, because it may contain values that would overflow the signed integer. Additionally, NSUInteger is either defined as unsigned int, or unsigned long depending on wether the platform is 32 or 64 bit, so you can handle this by casting to unsigned long and then using the unsigned long format specifier.

```
NSLog(@"The count of the book is now: %lu", (unsigned long)[book.book count]);
```